# add username in mutualcertificate ws-security header wcf

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, ws-security

After 1 week of research and try/retry, I did succeed to program nearly my need.

I am currently under a problem concerning ws-security signing in message.

So i am using soap12 with ws-security 1.0, framework 4.0 and mutual certificate in authenticationMode.

All is good in my request sent to webservice except that i need to put a username in the ws-security header.

If i put CertificateOverTransport, i have the username but the message is not signed enough.

Here is my binding :

```
<customBinding>
<binding name="NewBinding">
    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
        messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </textMessageEncoding>
    <security includeTimestamp="true"
            authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
                securityHeaderLayout="Strict"
            defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256"
            allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
            messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10">      
    </security>
    <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="true" />
</binding>
</customBinding>
```

Here is my behavior :

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="XXXXX" storeName="My" storeLocation="CurrentUser" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
        <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode ="PeerOrChainTrust" />
            <defaultCertificate findValue="XXXX" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>         
    </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My endpoint :

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="xxxx" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NewBinding" contract="WSSTestOutboundService"
        name="NewPort.0"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <identity>
        <dns value="XXXX"/>
    </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

Here is my code :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
{
    return true;
};

WSSTestOutboundServiceClient test = new WSSTestOutboundServiceClient();
test.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                        StoreLocation.CurrentUser
                    , StoreName.My
                    , X509FindType.FindByThumbprint
                    , "9f 28 4b 80 f1 fe 5c 9e ea 4d b4 a1 34 48 e2 47 b9 29 82 27");

test.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(
                        StoreLocation.CurrentUser
                    , StoreName.My
                    , X509FindType.FindBySubjectName
                    , "DPUPRGWYDP01.npr.bngf.local");
test.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign;

test.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "TEST";
test.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "TEST";
test.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "TEST2";
test.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "TEST2";

getGreeting test2 = new getGreeting();
MessageBox.Show(test.getGreeting(test2).greeting);
```

Please can you help me ?

A username in httprequest is not good enough.

Thank You!

////////////UPDATE////////////////

I managed to add this username token by adding it manually in endpoint information :

```
<endpoint address="https://XXXXXXX:443/TestSecurity/V1" binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NewBinding" contract="WSSTestOutboundService"
          name="NewPort.0"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
  <identity>
    <dns value="DPUPRGWYDP01.npr.bngf.local"/>
  </identity>
  <headers>
    <wsse:UsernameToken
      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
      wsu:Id="UsernameToken-6"
      xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:Username name="UserNameToken" value="Username"></wsse:Username>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </headers>
</endpoint>
```

But i don't know how to set the variable Username...

Have you any idea ?

Thank you!

////////////////UPDATE//////////////

This solution will not work because it is a multi-user application, so i can't modify config file.

I let the post here because it gives you an idea of what i am searching for.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Here is the code which add the username :

```
using (new OperationContextScope(test.InnerChannel))
{
    // Add a SOAP Header to an outgoing request
    //can't send username using mutualcertificate instead of using that way
    //can be better : see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/02/07/adding-custom-messageheader-and-http-header-to-a-wcf-method-call.aspx
    MessageHeader aMessageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UsernameToken", "http://tempuri.org", "TOTOTO");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(aMessageHeader);

    getGreeting test2 = new getGreeting();
    MessageBox.Show(test.getGreeting(test2).greeting);
}
```